# how to close all infoWIndown with button

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have page with google map

On the map i have number of pins. each one have an open infoWindow / popup

I would like to add button/link that will close all infoWindow at the same time.

This is my code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeAllInfoWindows();">Close all infowindows</a>

function closeAllInfoWindows()
{
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.close(map, markers);
}
```

code for the map:

```
 var markers = [
        <?PHP echo $markers ?>
];
window.onload = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: <?PHP echo $mapZoom ?>,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var lat_lng = new Array();
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });
        latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

        // open popup by click
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
        //

        // Open all popups
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: data.description
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);               
        //
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

}
```

Edit, here is Mayur code:

### -----------------------------------

```
 var markers = [
            <?PHP echo $markers ?>
    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: <?PHP echo $mapZoom ?>,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // HYBRID
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

            // open popup by click
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            //

            // Open all popups
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: data.description
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);               
            //
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    //  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Initialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var infoWindows = [];

            //add infowindow to array
            infoWindows.push(infowindow);       
        });

        function closeAllInfoWindows()
        {
            for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
               if (infoWindows[i])
                  infoWindows[i].close();
            }
        }           

    }
```

### ----------------

### ----------------

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the google map API docs, an Infowindow has a [close()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#InfoWindow)-method.

Collect all the Infowindows you create in an array. Then iterate over this array and call close for each Infowindow, when you need to close them all at once.

In the top, add an array to hold all the infoboxes created.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var infoWindows = [];
```

In loop, add below code after `infowindow.open(map, marker);` line to hold all your Infowindows in array.

```
//add infowindow to array
infoWindows.push(infowindow);
```

And finally, add below code of button and function to close all Infowindows with button.

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeAllInfoWindows();">Close all infowindows</a>

function closeAllInfoWindows()
{
    for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
       if (infoWindows[i])
          infoWindows[i].close();
    }
}
```

EDIT : As OP have placed code at wrong place in question.

```
    var markers = [
                <?PHP echo $markers ?>
        ];
    var infoWindows = [];
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: <?PHP echo $mapZoom ?>,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // HYBRID
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var lat_lng = new Array();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

                // open popup by click
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
                //

                // Open all popups
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: data.description
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);  

                //add infowindow to array
                infoWindows.push(infowindow);               
                //
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        //  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

            //***********ROUTING****************//

            //Initialize the Path Array
            var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

            //Initialize the Direction Service
            var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            //Set the Path Stroke Color
            var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });         

        }   

function closeAllInfoWindows()
            {
                for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
                   if (infoWindows[i])
                      infoWindows[i].close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. i edit my post and add your code -

Comment: This is working code I already have done the same thing with this code. Do you have  any console errors?

Comment: You have placed my code at the wrong place. I will edit my answer.

Comment: yes. Thank you! btw - is it possible to prevent the page from jumping to the top (when i click the link)?

Comment: Yes! You can add `javascript:void(0);` in `href` of `a` tag like `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="closeAllInfoWindows();">Close all infowindows</a>`

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Mayur, for opening, can i do this:  function openAllInfoWindows()
    {
  for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
     if (infoWindows[i])
     infoWindows[i].open();
  }
    }  


?

Comment: You need global `map` object and you need to store all  `marker` objects with `infowindow` to do this.

Comment: BTW you can add code between `` to display it as a formatted code in your comment.

Comment: so, for global map can i just add the word "global" before `var map = new google.maps.M...` ?

Comment: Global means variable should be accesible anywhere in your code. You have to move map init line before the load method starts. Move `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);` below  `var infoWindows = [];`.

Comment: well, i can't - the all thing stop working if i do that...`uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
ReferenceError: mapOptions is not defined`

Comment: Sorry. You need to move mapOptions as well in same sequence. One thing you need to understand is you need to init. variables before you use it.

Comment: ok, and than you wrote - "store all marker objects with infowindow" is that mean that i have to do the same as you did - `infoWindows.push(infowindow);    ` ?

Comment: Yes. Instead of 1D array you can use JSON dict to store both Infowindow and Marker object.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing it wrong, can you please write me the line?

Comment: Actually, I am about to leave an office. You can search for dynamic making of JSON dict and how to use it.

Comment: can i email you tomorrow?

Comment: You can ask a new question and share a question link with me and I will answer at there. I can't give an answer in a comment.

Comment: Ok, I opened new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906061/how-to-open-all-infowindows-with-button . Also, can i contact you directly - email?